# How to Open a Read/Write Handle with CreateFile on a Read-Only File

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

Hi I have a simple question - what are my options for opening a read/write handle with CreateFile on a read-only file? Do I have to remove the read-only attribute temporarily, open the handle, do the work, then reapply the attribute? Is there another way to do it? For my situation the program in question has administrative privileges.

Here's some code as things are now and what goes wrong:

```
HANDLE hTargetFile;
hTargetFile = CreateFile(QDir::toNativeSeparators(targetFileString).toStdWString().c_str(),GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
```

and I get **CreateFile failed with error 5: Access is denied.** from GetLastError().

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you've tried and also what `GetLastError()` returned when it failed to open the file. A [mre] would be good.

Comment: This reads like an administrative problem. Write access to a file system object is granted (or denied) based on its associated [access control list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-lists) matched against the caller.

Comment: You need remove read-only attribute, before you can write to file.

Comment: Is your processes the only writter? I would make a copy of the file. Create a read/write handle update the file approprirtely when finished replace the original with the new file. This prevents race conditions when you `remove the read-only attribute temporarily,`

Answer (score 3):

> what are my options for opening a read/write handle with CreateFile on a read-only file?

None.  You can't get a write handle to a read-only file.  `CreateFile()` will fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

> Do I have to remove the read-only attribute temporarily, open the handle, do the work, then reapply the attribute?

Yes, exactly.  And of course, that creates a race condition, because as soon as you remove the read-only attribute, any other process with adequate permissions to the file *could* open the file for writing and block you out before you are able to open the file yourself.

> Is there another way to do it?

Although APIs like `ReOpenFile()` and `SetFileInformationByHandle()` do exist, I was not able to figure out a way to use them to create a write handle to a read-only file (with or without removing the read-only attribute from the file) in way that would allow the caller to gain write access to the file while still preventing other processes from also gaining write access to the file.

I think [@MartinYork said it best in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304619/#comment136283844_77304619):

> I would make a copy of the file. Create a read/write handle update the file approprirtely when finished replace the original with the new file. This prevents race conditions when you remove the read-only attribute temporarily

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but it's an idea: `CreateFile` with only read rights in non-shared mode. Then remove the read-only attribute (while the file is open) and `ReOpenFile` with write access added? Closing would be done in a similar way: `ReOpenFile` with only read rights, add the read-only attribute again and then close it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I haven't tried it myself, but I question whether it would work: "*You cannot request an access mode that conflicts with the sharing mode specified in a previous open request whose handle is still open.*" Since the previous handle is not sharing write access, can it re-open the handle for write access? Unless the doc is talking about a separate open handle and not the one being re-opened, I guess that would make more sense.

Comment: Aha, right, that sounds like a probable showstopper.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Indeed. I just tried it. If the initial `CreateFile()` opens the file for reading access and no write sharing, then the attribute is removed, `ReOpenFile()` for write access still fails with `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. If `CreateFile()` opens the file with writing sharing, then `ReOpenFile()` succeeds, but that defeats the purpose, as anyone could just use `CreateFile()` instead with writing access.

Comment: Yes, the key would be to be able to do it in non-shared mode. Bummer :-) Great that you tried it out though!